# Phrases in Spanish that are almost identical to English - who influenced whom?

Tags: etimología, historia, inglés

There are quite many language constructs in (Latin American) Spanish that resemble English. Examples:

- fuera de servicio - out of service
- tener un punto - to have a point
- marcar la diferencia - to make a difference

This can't be a coincidence. So are these imports to Spanish from English? Or are these Latin constructs that arrived into both, English and Spanish? The latter seems less likely.

Comment: It is interesting to check Google Ngram for all these expressions in both languages. Their curve of usage is quite similar, normally with the English version appearing first.

Comment: I like this question. I bet there are good answers ready to come.

Comment: This question is interesting, but the answer might vary from expression to expression. I would say that as a "rule of thumb" they have a common "ancestor" in Latin or the meaning is quite plain simple/literal. If it is an expression/coloquilism (a sentence that doesn't mean the literal meaning of it's words) then you might need to go case by case. I don't think that there is a "**one size fits all**" solution/explanation for this, and even if we assumed one of the hypothesis there would be plenty of exceptions.  To me this question looks a little bit too broad.

Comment: I've just edited *afuera* to *fuera*, which is the right form.

Comment: @MikeMarsian I find "marcar la diferencia" to be quite different from "make a difference" (different verb, different article).

Comment: In Mexico is quite common to say "hacer la diferencia", a literal translation of to make a difference. I cringe everytime I hear it.

Comment: @walen, yo habría votado para cerrar, pero al votar como moderador la pregunta quedaría cerrada sin más, y no quería hacerlo de forma unilateral. Esperaba que la comunidad decidiese (mejor la opinión de cinco personas que la de una para estas preguntas que son _casos límite_). No sé si el resto de usuarios no vota porque habéis visto que los moderadores ya nos hemos pasado por aquí y no la hemos cerrado. A veces dejamos pasar un tiempo con ciertas preguntas para que la comunidad tenga tiempo de evaluarlas y consensuar. Sentíos libres de votar para cerrar/(re)abrir o discutirlo en meta.

Comment: @walen The ideal answer I am looking for is one that explains whether there is some broader historic tendency that would explain many of these occurrences. For example, one explanation offered by someone to me was that these are gallicisms, e.g. idioms loaned from the 18th century French. For that reason I would rather the question wasn't split. 

If there is no such general tendency, and each such phrase has its own history, that that would be the answer.

Comment: @Gustavson even though "marcar la diferencia" isn't exactly the same as "make a difference", they are too close to be unrelated. For example, In two other languages I speak - Russian and Hebrew there is nothing remotely similar.

Comment: @Diego to return the favor :-)  .... your comment already has +6 votes and you should make it an answer. [**I would say that as a "rule of thumb" they have a common "ancestor" in Latin or the meaning is quite plain simple/literal.**]

Answer (score 6):

I would say that as a "rule of thumb", when two expressions are so similar, they have a common "ancestor" in Latin, but it might be impossible to assure for all cases.

In other cases, the meaning might be quite plain simple and literal. Take for example the famous `"Not all that glitters is gold"`, which is attributed to Shakespeare's *The Merchant of Venice* (believed to have been written between 1596 and 1599). The expression `"No es oro todo lo que reluce"` appears in chapter XXXI of Cervantes' "El ingenioso hidalgo Don Quijote de la Mancha" (published in 1605, so people claim that Shakespeare's coined this expression and others just copied/reused it), but in La Celestina (published in 1499) we find the very similar `"En la tina, todo lo blanco no es harina"` <sup>1</sup>. Which highlight that this expression (or a similar one) is quite popular and common in most modern languages.

In a similar way compare:

- don't look a gift horse in the mouth
- a caballo regalado no se le mira el diente

Looking at a horse's teeth is the best way of knowing if they are healthy. That's why the sayings are so similar. The root of the  meaning is literal but now it gets used for other contexts. Other examples:

- Better late than never (Spanish version is the literal translation "mejor tarde que nunca)
- A man is known by the company he keeps ("Dime con quién andas y te diré quién eres")

Sometimes sayings and proverbs might differ in wording, but meaning is the same

- If you run after two hares you will catch neither (Quien mucho abarca, poco aprieta)
- Better the devil you know than the devil you don’t know (más vale malo conocido que bueno por conocer)

If it is an expression/coloquialism (a sentence that doesn't mean the literal meaning of it's words) then you might need to go case by case. I don't think that there is a "one size fits all" solution/explanation for this, and even if we assumed one of the hypothesis (either "it comes from common ancestor", "meaning is quite literal" or "Language A influenced language B") there would be plenty of exceptions.

---

1- [CVC: No es oro todo lo que reluce](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/ficha.aspx?Par=59168&Lng=0)

2- [25 refranes en diferentes idomas](https://verne.elpais.com/verne/2015/08/10/articulo/1439209249_359956.html) (article in Spanish)